# How to set up a promotion rule which enable users to get additional discount for certain bank card holder?

Tags: magento2, promotions, rules

Does anyone know how to set up a promotion rule which enable users to get additional discount for certain bank card holder?
Can we create it in Magento 2 default or can anyone suggest an extension if needed.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly complicated request and can change across regions and banks. This module does not exist in Magento Connect (or at least I can find one). You will have to make this functionality via the custom module that you install in your Magento store.

Comment: Thanks @Sandeep. Do u know any extension which can help?